# access query count if same record add on new row?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

For examples I have this access table

```
fruit    person         price
apple    jhon            5
apple    mary            12
pear     alison          10
grape    kim             12 
grape    kim             24
grape    jack            9
```

How we can count fruit and added another fields(couNum) like that ?

```
couNum      fruit    person         price 
   1        apple    jhon            5
   2        apple    mary            12
   1        pear     alison          10
   1        grape    kim             12
   2        grape    kim             24
   3        grape    jack            9
```

Please help thanks.

Comment: use `control-k` or add 4 spaces to format as code

Comment: it must be access query

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the relation predicate (what each row of your table 'means') e.g. how is `{ grape, kim, 12 }` different from `{ grape, kim, 24 }` - Kim charges twice for every grape he sells but what does "charging twice" mean?

Answer (score 1):

This is painful to do in MS Access, but you can do it with a subquery -- assuming that you have a unique column for each row:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from t as t2
        where t2.fruit = t.fruit and t2.person <= t.person
       ) as couNum
from t;
```

In most other databases, you would simply use `row_number()`.  If you are learning SQL and have a choice on what database to use, I would steer you to one of the more "up-to-date" databases such as Postgres, MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, or almost anything else.

Comment: "This is painful to do in MS Access" - it looks it. IIRC Access has a nice report tool. Would this be less painful as a report?